# How to increment a variable and insert sql php?

Tags: php, sql

this is my first time programming and I need a little help on this one.
I have a code that I get the $year from a form and i want to increment it until an end year and insert the result in the data base:

```
include 'conect.php';

$user=  $_POST['user'];
$school= $_POST['school'];
$year= $_POST['year'];
$endyear= $_POST['endyear'];
```

The insertion into the database should repeat those variables until $endyear, something like this:

```
ROW 1:
user: John
school: UFPS
year: 2010 

ROW 2:
user: John
school: UFPS
year: 2011

ROW 3:
user: John
school: UFPS
year: 2012
```

What if I have to increment more then one Variable? for example:

```
$user= $_POST['user']; 
$school= $_POST['school']; 
$year= $_POST['year']; 
$endyear= $_POST['endyear']; 
$day= $_POST['startday']; 
$endday = $_POST['endday'];
```

And increment until an $endyear and also endday?

result: 
ROW 1: user: John school: UFPS year: 2010 day:1 
ROW 2: user: John school: UFPS year: 2011 day:2 
ROW 3: user: John school: UFPS year: 2012 day:3

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have sanitized your POST data against SQL injection attacks, you can use a loop:

```
for( $y = $year; $y <= $endyear; $y++ )
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO [yourtablename] (user, school, year) VALUES ('$user', '$school', $y)";
   // execute query
}
```

You could also potentially build and extended query in the loop and execute it once afterwards.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [yourtablename] (user, school, year)";
for( $y = $year; $y <= $endyear; $y++ )
{
   $query .= "VALUES ('$user', '$school', $y)".($y < $endyear ? ',': '');
}
// execute query
```

Comment: Your latter suggestion is best. To build then execute only once.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want is a decent PHP tool to connect to your database, like PDO or an addon like ADOdb. Assuming you already have built your table structure, using PDO, it would go like this:

```
for( $i = intval($year); $i <= intval($endyear); $i++ )
{
   $sql = "INSERT INTO ".DATABASE_TABLE_NAME_CONSTANT." (user, school, year) VALUES (?,?,?)";
   $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array($user,$school,$i));
}
```

More info on PDO [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

You should also get into the habit of keeping all your table names in constants. The reason is that some hosting services limit you to 1 database. Keeping it in constants would allow you to run a sandbox version of your project alongside a production version in the same database. All you need is a different prefix, like in the sandbox, you prefix tablenames with sb_ and in production, with pr_. For example:

```
define("USERS_TABLE", $config["tbl_prefix"]."users");
```

Comment: And how do you sync the schema if table names are different?

Comment: Why would you even have to do that? If you add a table or column, add it with an update script, change prefixes. I would never trust a tool to modify a database that is in production, that is utterly stupid.

Comment: So you would say you will not trust a tool like SVN for example to merge your code on production, you are going to copy-paste the differences by yourself or by written by you tool? The same way the version source control is used, so do the database control

Comment: I actually do not trust SVN merges for production either. A mistake is easily made. I set up my sandbox to run temporarily on prod, when I check all is right on test accounts, then I switch filenames and it works instantly. Never do anything on prod, just like you wouldn't compile C# at the client's offices and test it there.

Comment: It does not work on big projects. Bad practice and a lot of waste of time which you need to pay to a QA to test your prod environment the way you do.

Comment: Well clients and patrons tend to appreciate it when they are not your QA. It's kinda cheap to let clients be that QA.

Comment: It works if you are in beta stage. Once you say you product is official, you cannot afford bugs to your costumers

Comment: Precisely, so why would you merge anything to prod? You should always have a "beta" stage that when it is perfect, then it gets promoted to production. The old production is archived so you can revert easily, but no merges on prod directly.

Comment: Usually the users are not using your 'beta'/test environment, and will not do it for nothing. You have development environments but there only your QA's are testing. Once they give you green light, you merge to prod. No further painful weeks long testing. On the other side, when you start your project from the beginning, your 'production' environment where you merge from 'development' could still be beta, and users are aware that even after tests in dev, they can experience problems. But afterwards, once you say them it's not beta anymore - cannot afford bugs after merge

Comment: I don't see how changing a folder name and a config file means more testing. Especially when you script the folder name changes, its impossible to make any kind of mistake, whereas a merge can have issues if someone adds the wrong files and those mistakes land on prod. It is much worse than having bugs.

Comment: It means, because you cannot copy all the folder to the prod server and just change the name. You know, there might be features that are not scheduled to be released yet, only half of the work should be merged. So if a certain sprint contains 50 modified files, 20 new files and 10 new folders with 10 new files each, but only half of them should be merged, it will be real pain to do it copy/pase/rename and you might not do it as good as needed, so it needs further testing. On other hand you can tell SVN merge this, this and this revision or from this developer revisions only

Comment: With some developers I saw, that way leads to mistakes. Some change functions without saying anything for example, to fit their code, breaking previous code. You must put your release candidate in a single site and test that. Nothing else. If its good, then your devs can merge all of the new prod into their code and work from there. 

You know, it is not a pain to name a folder site1 and have a test folder sandbox_site1 then just rename site1 to site1_arch_date and sandbox_site1 to site1 and restore a db config file on the new site1. I dont understand why you would rename all files.

Comment: ie: If its not meant to be released, it shouldn't be on your sandbox site, the dev working on it can work in a local sandbox and once it is ready, merge his work with the online sandbox for testing purposes, never in prod.

Comment: This is why version controll is here - of that unwanted changes. If you development release (before the QA has to test) is i.e. 05.08.2013, your dev's should be ready until this date on you dev/rc or whatever called server. Then 1 week the QA's are testing. Nobody should change function while testing, except the QA report a bug there. If someone changes something, it will be easily tracked with the subversion. Also the SVN commits save history of all revisions and conflicts while just replacing a file won't do it

Comment: Why not? Let's say on your project you are going to implement 5 new features (call them f1, f2.. f5). f1 Should be on your sandbox for QA's to test on 05.08, f2 on 10.08, f3 on 17.08, f4 on 23.08 and f5 on 31.08. On the prod env, f1 should be released on 14.08, f2 on 20.08. If using your way, both f1 and f2 will be on sandbox for QA's to test on 14.08, but only f1 should be merged on production.

Comment: Two features in 6 days? Users will wait 6 days and get both at once. We do not owe anyone feature updates. And even if we did, the sales rep would have to make the client understand that their version is delayed. If anyone truly depends on a feature and 6 days will break it, they already messed up anyways.

Comment: In my case we are working in the online rpg games industry. A single game needs new features on regular intervals, but not at once. Like events - event for this week, for next week. They start on 05.08 and end on 09.08, a new one should start i.e. on 11.08, not two events on 11.08, because users cannot afford the time and money to play it and will be disappointed of the aggressive monetarized policy.

Comment: An online RPG even on a website should be treated as an application, not a web site so the whole dev cycle is different. On another app, in C#, we have everything under 3-tiered code architecture behind SVN, but I don't do the mergers for that, nor would I want to. 

Anyhow, waiting on EQN. :D

Comment: Yeah, it depends how you look on your app :) I'm always trying to look on any single even small site as a big enough application, so to take advantage of every good practice :):)

Comment: Good practice on the cheapest hosting sites is very hard thing to actually follow. What I do works with 1 database and FTP access. To me best practice is what is safer, not what is most effective. The lower the risk, the better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use auto_increment (on the database .. I don't know what you are using) and set a default value to the starting year.

Comment: This would work if you only had one user. I'm assuming there are multiple users/student.